# How do I implement Azure Search Service in Sitefinity?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, sitefinity, azure-search-.net-sdk

Does any know of any examples out there that show how to implement ISearchService using Azure search service in Sitefinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitefinity supports Azure search out of the box. And you don't need to implement your own `ISearchService`.

This is official documentation how to connect your Sitefintiy to Azure search service: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/generate-and-store-search-indexes-in-the-cloud

Answer (score 1):

The closest one I found is from their official forum:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/search-mark-a-field-in-azure-search-as-facetable